# Use WMI filtering to ensure a user is in a specific OU

Tags: wmi-query, gpo

I am currently creating a WMI filter for a GPO so that the policy is only run on users who are in a certain OU.

I found a tutorial that explains how to do this for PC's, so adapted it to users, but it's not working.

So part one of my question - does anybody know how to successfully do this? So far I have this, but it's not working (using the `root\RSOP\User` namespace) -

```
Select * From RSOP_Session Where SOM = 'OU=Sherborne Users,OU=Users,OU=DD,DC=dynedrewett,DC=com'
```

And part two - how can I inspect the namespaces that are available for WMI filtering, to she what they contain? This would help to ensure I am actually checking the right thing! Thanks.

Comment: Have you managed to find if it is possible to do this?  Everything I've searched and read suggests that it is not.

Comment: No joy I'm afraid, I still have issues but am unable to resolve them.